# GNU Stow: ERROR: Slashes are not permitted in package names

Tags: gnu, dot-files, stow

Got the error stow: ERROR: slashes are not permited in package names when using `stow --simulate -v --target=/path/to/target/tree /path/to/source/tree`

What wrong I'm doing??

Answer (score 2):

Stow expects as an argument a package name -- like "gcc" or "vim" or "foo" or "my-awesome-packge" -- rather than a path like `/path/to/source/tree`. It will by default look for that package in the local directory and then symlink it into the parent directory (or into whichever directory you specify with `--target` if you don't like the default).

In other words, if I have directory `/usr/local/stow` containing:

```
packagea/
  bin/
    packagea
packageb/
  bin/
    packageb
  share/
    man/
      man1/
        packageb.1
```

Then I can `cd` into `/usr/local/stow` and run `stow packagea` or `stow packageb`, and `stow` will create the necessary symlinks:

- For `stow packagea`, `/usr/local/bin/packagea` would point to `/usr/local/stow/package/bin/pacakge`
- For `stow packageb`:

  - `/usr/local/bin/packageb` would link to `/usr/local/stow/packageb/bin/packageb`
  - `/usr/local/share/man/man1/packageb.1` would link to `/usr/local/stow/packageb/share/man/man1/packageb.1`

Like this:

```
# cd /usr/local/stow
# tree
.
└── packageb
    ├── bin
    │   └── packageb
    └── share
        └── man
            └── man1
                └── packageb.1
# stow --simulate -v packageb
LINK: bin/packageb => ../stow/packageb/bin/packageb
LINK: share/man/man1/packageb.1 => ../../../stow/packageb/share/man/man1/packageb.1
WARNING: in simulation mode so not modifying filesystem.
```

---

If I want to manage `/usr/share/powerline/config_files/themes/tmux/default.json` with stow, I might do something like the following. Here, `/root/stow` is my stow directory (but it could be anywhere), and I'm using `/usr/share` as my target directory.

1. Before I start, I have:

   ```
   # tree /usr/share/powrline
   /usr/share/powrline/
   └── config_files
       └── themes
           ├── file1.txt
           ├── file2.txt
           ├── file3.txt
           ├── file4.txt
           └── file5.txt
   ```
2. In my stow directory:

   ```
   mkdir -p powrline/powrline/config_files/themes/tmux
   echo '{"this": "is a test"}' > powrline/powrline/config_files/themes/tmux/default.json
   ```

   This gives me:

   ```
   # tree
   .
   └── powrline
       └── powrline
           └── config_files
               └── themes
                   └── default.json
   ```
3. And then, also in my stow directory:

   ```
   stow --target=/usr/share powrline
   ```
4. This will give me:

   ```
   # tree /usr/share/powrline/
   /usr/share/powrline/
   └── config_files
       └── themes
           ├── default.json -> ../../../../../root/stow/powrline/powrline/config_files/themes/default.json
           ├── file1.txt
           ├── file2.txt
           ├── file3.txt
           ├── file4.txt
           └── file5.txt
   ```

I could of course decode to use something other than `/usr/share` as the target: e.g., I could use `/usr/share/powrline` as my target directory, in which case my stow directory would look like:

```
.
└── powrline
    └── config_files
        └── themes
            └── default.json
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. What i want to do is is want to keep track of one file located in `/usr/share/powerline/config_files/themes/tmux/default.json`. and my stow package is at `~/dotfiles/powerline/usr/share/powerline/config_files/themes/default.json`. If I stowd it , would it overwrite all of the package content , or it'll just symlind this file `default.json` to it's equivalent in the target directory?

Comment: Stow will only create symlinks for files that exist in your package directory. It won't touch other files. If you want to be sure, just create  a copy of e.g. `/usr/share/powerline/` somewhere else and test that as your `--target` directory.

Comment: NONE of the following is working for me: `stow --simulate -v --target=/usr/share/powrline/config_files/themes/tmux powrline` `stow --simulate -v --target='/usr/share/powrline/config_files/themes/tmux' powrline` `stow --simulate -v --target="/usr/share/powrline/config_files/themes/tmux" powrline`

Comment: If you'd like to update your question to show the actual layout of your stow directory I'd be happy to take a look. With what you've posted in your comment there's really not enough information to figure out what's going on.

Comment: How to give the target directory path to the `--target` option?

Comment: I've updated my answer in light of your comments. I don't think I can be any more explicit than this.